# Kubernetes Installation with Vagrant & CoreOS: kubectl can't work

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes, coreos, kubectl

I followed this introduction to  launching a multi-node Kubernetes cluster using Vagrant and CoreOS:

https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html

All my work is as the default.

In the last, there is one note in the webpage.

When the cluster is first launched, it must download all container images for the cluster components (Kubernetes, dns, heapster, etc). Depending on the speed of your connection, it can take a few minutes before the Kubernetes api-server is available. Before the api-server is running, the kubectl command above may show output similar to:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 172.17.4.101:443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I can see from my system monitor, it downloads something about 2M/s for a while. But when the download finished, I couldn't get the nodes either.

I don't know why this happened. Thank you so much if you could try this as the webpage instruction.

Comment: If you ssh in to the machine and run `docker ps` can you see the API server running?

Comment: @3ocene I can't see that and there is not any images. If this means that I didn't pull the images? I'm in china now, and I can't access to google. I saw someone post the images about kubernetes to dockerhub. But I don't know which ones should I pull. Could you help me about this, thank you so much!